# Experiment.java:18: error: illegal start of expression

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Experiment 
{
 private int periodCount = 0;
 private String para = "";
  
 public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException
    {  
   
      
   Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("example.dat"));
   
   public int getNumberString()
     {
      String vowels = " ";
      int count = 0;
      String para = file("example.dat");
      for(int index = 0; index < para.length(); index++)
      {
         if(vowels.indexOf(para.charAt(index)) >= 0)
         {
            count++;
         }
         
         return count;  
       }
     
    } 
        //file.nextLine();
            
    public int periodCounter() 
     {
      int size = getNumberString();
      
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
           if(para.charAt(i + 1) == '.')
            periodCount++;   
           
        }
        return periodCount;
     } 
     
  public String Decider()
  {
     
    if(periodCount() <= 30)
        return "Average";
    if (periodCount() >= 30)
        return "high";    
        
  }
   
   
    System.out.println("This paragragh is a reading level" + Decider());
   
   
   }
```

Hi! to be clear I was just messing around with this but now I want to see if it will work. The goal is to take count of the number of spaces in a paragraph on a dat file document and use that as a stopping point for a method to find the number of periods in a paragraph and determine the reading level from there.

I'm pretty new to java so this is just me throwing things around that I think will work

The issue is that it says both
my getNumberString and periodCounter functions are `Experiment.java:18: error: illegal start of expression` and that my print command is `Experiment.java:45: error: <identifier> expected` and  `Experiment.java:45: error: illegal start of type`

additionally, if you find any thing you might want to comment on feel free to!!

Comment: You have put a method inside a method.  That's not valid Java.

Answer (score 1):

Look where your { and } match up. You've defined getNumberString() inside the body of your main() method. You're probably missing a closing } after your Scanner declaration line (and some other code that calls your other methods.

"Experiment.java:18: error: illegal start of expression" is telling you that you can't start a method declaration at this location, this is not valid syntax.